# X ssh forwarding not working from a macOS 13.4.1 to Debian Linux 11

Tags: unix, ssh, ventura, x11, xquartz

I have currently an issue about trying to get a SSH X forwarding connection from a macOS Ventura to a Debian Linux 11. I am using XQuartz 2.8.4 (2.8.5 failed in installation).

I don't know where the problem comes from. Below a lot of informations with `-vvv` option :

```
ssh -X -vvv fab@pablo 
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to pablo port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fab/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to pablo:22 as 'fab'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 2 keys from pablo
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:GLFoF6k2v/2MxuWrF1yK62AkZHsxKjH15LdXOC8PNIY
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 2 keys from pablo
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'pablo' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/fab/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
fab@pablo's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to pablo ([192.168.1.62]:22) using "password".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:/qSKL8wq3JtHIJiXzu+62UH3nbjm+fObXjBofpoqPyo
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:76LnGQ12/LisJhH5vvrWgCdn2I/oxOzhcuLnO9+6LYQ
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:GLFoF6k2v/2MxuWrF1yK62AkZHsxKjH15LdXOC8PNIY
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts for pablo / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts2 for pablo / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 1 new, 1 retained, 1 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: asking server to prove ownership for 1 keys
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: client_x11_get_proto: xauth command: /opt/X11/bin/xauth -f /var/folders/1n/6wz8wzkn63n8y1zc2xjcm6640000gn/T//ssh-Tw35M0laihwY/xauthfile generate /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.qpHhyhgMf3/org.xquartz:0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 untrusted timeout 1260 2>/dev/null
```

It seems that XQuartz doesn't open the X after typing the password, I don't understand.

If someone has already got this type of issue or sees its cause, I am lost with these many log informations ...

**UPDATE 1 :** Here an example (where I have deleted the known_hosts on both side) :

```
$ ssh -Y fab@pablo
The authenticity of host 'pablo (192.168.1.62)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:GLFoF6k2v/2MxuWrF1yK62AkZHsxKjH15LdXOC8PNIY.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'pablo' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
fab@pablo's password:
Linux pablo 5.10.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-2 (2023-07-14) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Aug  2 01:17:43 2023 from 192.168.1.66
```

and doesn't display the rest.

**UPDATE 2 :** I keep on my investigations about my issue. I found out that if I set on remote the environment variable to `DISPLAY=localhost:10.0`, then the X of server is working ( after a `ssh -Y fab@pablo` ) : I mean, I can launch for example `nedit` from remote machine and the window will appear on my macOS  Ventura.

I realized there is a code snippet into the ~/.zshrc of current user on remote machine :

```
############ FOR X11 Fowarding ##############

if [ -e "$DISPLAY" ]; then
  DISPDIR=$(dirname $DISPLAY)
  NEWDISP="${DISPDIR}/:0"
  if [ ! -e "$NEWDISP" ]; then
    ln -s "$DISPLAY" "$NEWDISP"
    xauth -q generate "$NEWDISP" .
  fi
  export DISPLAY="$NEWDISP"
fi
```

but I don't remember what this part does exactly. Ideally, I would like that ssh connextion puts automatically the right value for variable `DISPLAY` : either directly on the machine (`127.0.0.1:0.0`) and from the macOS (`127.0.0.1:10`) when I do a `ssh -X fab@pablo`.

Comment: Could anyone epxlain me please the goal of the small code snippet present in the **UPDATE 2** ( ############ FOR X11 Fowarding ############## ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the connection hang after these messages or is there more information in the terminal?

I looked closely at the last lines and assume that the problem is on one side with the known_hosts file. The server cannot prove ownership for 1 key.

```
1: debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts2 for pablo / (none)
2: debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /Users/fab/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
3: debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 1 new, 1 retained, 1 incomplete match. 0 to remove
4: debug3: client_input_hostkeys: asking server to prove ownership for 1 keys
5: debug3: send packet: type 80
6: debug3: receive packet: type 91
7: debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
8: debug2: client_x11_get_proto: xauth command: /opt/X11/bin/xauth -f /var/folders/1n/6wz8wzkn63n8y1zc2xjcm6640000gn/T//ssh-Tw35M0laihwY/xauthfile generate /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.qpHhyhgMf3/org.xquartz:0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 untrusted timeout 1260 2>/dev/null
```

Why are 3 keys found on line 3?

Try removing all wrong entries in known_hosts file. Check this on both sides.

Comment: Yes, the connection hangs after these messages, I enter my password and I have the pompt message but doesn't return hand.

Comment: However, a simple connection (without X flag) works very well.

Comment: @guizmo133 Do you use the option `ForwardX11 yes` in the .ssh/config file of your client for host pablo?

Comment: for an unknow reason, there is no config files `~/.ssh/ssh_config` on my macOS ventura. But I haven't it also on the remote machine ( Debian 11 ) . The only place where I have a `ssh_config` file on the Debian machine is in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` with `ForwardX11 yes`. Where is the  `ssh_config` file for local macOS machine ? Regards

Comment: @guizmo133 `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file is for the ssh-server. On your macOS ventura, an ssh config file is not mandatory, but maybe it can narrow down the error. Create a file on your macOS ventura `touch ~/.ssh/config`. Then add an entry for pablo (use the IP instead of pablo) like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56536275/1307889 but add `ForwardX11 yes`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I have created on macOS venture a `ssh_config` file with the content :

`Host *`

`#   ForwardAgent no`

`ForwardX11 yes`

 `ForwardX11Trusted yes`

But ssh -X or ssh_Y doesn't return hand when I try to connect from macOS to Debian lInux. An clues ?

Comment: Ok last try: check this site with all comments https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely is your environment variable `DISPLAY` on the debian server set?